# Log in user without giving access to admin interface

Tags: django

Working on a project that is powered by Django. Problem is I can't seem to find the way how to authenticate user without giving him access to the admin interface at the same time. I've read through numerous articles and tutorials about how Django handles authenticating visitors of the website and they all seem to go through creating user in admin and build a separate view for visitors to see where they're presented with login form to fill out.

They don't seem to address the problem what if the user finds out that the website is built in Django, types "/admin hits enter and then just types in his/her credentials and vuala random visitor is in admin interface which isn't good at all ?

Comment: If you don't set the `is_staff` attribute to True for that specific user, they will not be able to login to admin.

Comment: @ayhan Really ? So all I need is make sure the staff checkbox remains unchecked and it will prevent them from accessing admin ? Great !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for [`is_staff`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff)

> Boolean. Designates whether this user can access the admin site.

Comment: I must've missed this line when researching in the docs. Cheers.